# If i started the game i got this error: Can't send RPC function since no connection was started

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc

I have a problem with RPC calls in unity.
This is my script with rpc:

```
[RPC]
public void TestRPC ()
{
   Debug.Log("Test");
}    
nView.RPC ("TestRPC",RPCMode.Others);
```

If I started a game I got this error:

> Can't send RPC function since no connection was started.
>   UnityEngine.NetworkView:RPC(String, RPCMode, Object[])
>   c__IteratorC:MoveNext() (at
>   Assets/_Scripts/Weapon_rifle_test.cs:172)
>   UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String)
>   Weapon_rifle_test:Update() (at
>   Assets/_Scripts/Weapon_rifle_test.cs:87)

Can you help me?

Comment: check this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/329028/cant-send-rpc-function-since-no-connection-was-sta.html)

Comment: I checked it, and it isn't works. To create server I use Network Manager HUD

Comment: Can you see whether you are connected or not? I haven't worked with the RPC so i just guessing but maybe it helps :)

Comment: Yes, if I using script from his link. But I didn't recive any messages

Comment: Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check if client is connected before making the RPC call.

```
if(Network.isClient) {
    nView.RPC ("TestRPC",RPCMode.Others);
}
```